# How to build and install Valgrind on Mac?

Tags: build, valgrind

I am on Mac OS X using codeblocks 10.05

I downloaded Valgrind, and extracted a folder. I am completely lost from there, and have no idea how to build it.

I do not know ANY terminal/console commands and am generally new to programming, so I have no idea how to "build" or "compile" it. I just have a folder called Valgrind with a bunch of random files in it.

Could someone please tell me how to proceed? I already checked the website/documentation but it didn't really give me installation instructions, just usage instructions.

Thanks

PS: I know I already posted this question, but the previous question was shut down, for being too vague. I reposted this one with more info.

PSS: All that I am basically asking is what do I do to install Valgrind right after I download it from the website and extract the files?

Comment: @tjm sorry ill remove the "shouting". I don't really understand what you mean by detail. All Im asking is - I have downloaded Valgrind, what do I do next?

Mankarse I didn't know that, thank you for the info :)

Comment: There is information on how to install Valgrind in the official documentation. [link](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/dist.install.html)

Comment: Look at the `README` file in the directory that came out of the archive when you extracted it. That file has instructions on how to configure and build, so give that a try.

Comment: Thank you :)
The README file says to run "make", but I can't find a file named "make". Do you know what to do?

Comment: With all due respect, asking how to build and install `valgrind` without knowing your way around the `bash` shell or knowing how to use `sudo` is like trying to program without learning to use a text editor. You're skipping too many steps.

Comment: If you know that little about using the command line, you need to read a tutorial on using it. Valgrind will be useless if you don't understand how to use the command line.

Comment: @Mike DeSimone Duly noted :)
Could you maybe recommend me a good tutorial for command line? Because I am generally good at programming, just not familiar with command line

Comment: [Learning the bash shell](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596009656.do) and [UNIX in a Nutshell](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565924277.do) are what comes to mind.

Comment: Questions related to tools that developers use are on topic here, and people _do_ often need to use a newer version of Valgrind to get around bugfixes or get access to new features. The comments related to the OP's command line proficiency aren't really constructive.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

## Recommended:

Use `brew`: `brew install valgrind`

## Manual Install:

Here's what worked on my Mac (10.6). Double-check you have the latest version, then change into the uncompressed directory

```
cd /users/(insert username here)/downloads/valgrind-3.17.0
```

I suggest you do as another posted and read the readme.

```
nano README
```

Commence the build; `/usr/local` is the place on the filesystem that the program will be installed to. There are many arguments like `prefix` that are available to customize the installation to your particular system if it doesn't work by default. Normally just using `./configure` works perfectly well though.

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local

make

sudo make install
```

Or you could probably get it from fink or macports or homebrew.

Comment: I don't recommend using `./configure --prefix=/usr/bin` for other users. I did this and the test in README didn't work (the system didn't have `valgrind` in its path). Just using plain `./configure` worked well for me.

Comment: I had a similar experience. using `--prefix=/usr/bin`made valgrind unavailable in system path, but leaving out that `--prefix` did.

Comment: @Soonts There is no "correct prefix", you could install it anywhere you like.

Comment: @joshua.thomas.bird Apparently, the install script included in valgrind appends “bin” to the end of the prefix you specify. If you specify `--prefix=/usr/bin`, it will be installed in `/usr/bin/bin`, and that’s why I think it’s not correct.

Comment: Just realized you're totally right. I must've made a typo 7 years ago and not known.

Comment: @joshua.thomas.bird They might have updated their install script in that 7 years.

Comment: Well I've updated the answer to reflect that, and also put a little more info about config options in case anyone else runs into similar things.

Comment: Dear joshua, for some tragic reason, brew appears to be unable to install it on my MacOSX Mojave `10.14.6` , and says : `valgrind: This formula either does not compile or function as expected on macOS
versions newer than High Sierra due to an upstream incompatibility.`

Answer (score 20):

You can install it through brew for Mac:

```
brew install valgrind
```

You might have to manually link the entry to `/usr/local/bin` as brew refused to do it in my case:

```
$ ln /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/3.8.1/bin/vgdb /usr/local/bin/vgdb
ln: /usr/local/bin/vgdb: Permission denied
$ sudo ln /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/3.8.1/bin/vgdb /usr/local/bin/vgdb
```

Comment: Seems like you might have to install it from head to get this to work, [as detailed here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27408219/26510)

Comment: It seems your directory permissions are not correct. Homebrew should be able to write to your /usr/local without sudo. See https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/19670.

Comment: I don't know why using brew is not the accepted answer for "How do I install X on a Mac."

Comment: @BradParks installing from HEAD worked, but on my machine I get `configure: error: Valgrind works on Darwin 10.x, 11.x, 12.x, 13.x, 14.x, 15.x, 16.x and 17.x (Mac OS X 10.6/7/8/9/10/11 and macOS 10.12/13)` running macOS Mojave Version `10.14.3`

Comment: I haven't tried it, but [this post on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52732036/26510) suggests a solution, @GregDegruy

Comment: This fails with an error: `valgrind: Linux is required for this software.`

Answer (score 13):

## On MacOS High Sierra

#### If you have the following error message:

```
brew install valgrind
valgrind: This formula either does not compile or function as expected on macOS
versions newer than Sierra due to an upstream incompatibility.
```

#### Fix

**(1)** To correctly install it, first, type the following command at the Terminal (which opens Valgrind’s formulae)

```
brew edit valgrind
```

And change the URL in head section

```
https://sourceware.org/git/valgrind.git
```

to

```
git://sourceware.org/git/valgrind.git
```

**(2)** Do an update for Homebrew:

```
brew update
```

**(3)** Finally, use the following command to install Valgrind from the HEAD:

```
brew install --HEAD valgrind
```

#### Sources

- https://www.gungorbudak.com/blog/2018/04/28/how-to-install-valgrind-on-macos-high-sierra/
- https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/18998

Comment: I can confirm that this sadly doesn't work for OS Catalina (10.15 +)

Answer (score 11):

**For macOS Big Sur / Monterey:**

```
brew tap LouisBrunner/valgrind
brew install --HEAD LouisBrunner/valgrind/valgrind
```

Comment: `Error: Valgrind is currently incompatible with ARM-based Macs, see https://github.com/LouisBrunner/valgrind-macos/issues/56`

Answer (score 3):

The core process is pretty simple:

Make sure you are in the correct directory.

First run:

```
./configure
```

when that is finished, run:

```
make
```

at this point you will need to `su` into root (this is relatively tricky to do, see the note at the end). As root, run:

```
make install
```

When this is finished you will have a working valgrind installation. Test it by running

```
valgrind ls -l
```

---

To `su` into root, you will need to have set up a root account. If you have not done this in the past, see the instructions from apple [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1528).

To perform the actual `su`, you will first have to be running an account with administrator privileges. If you are not already doing so, you can switch users with the following:

```
su admin
```

where `admin` is the name of an user with administrator privileges (you will need to enter the password for this account). From there, you can then run `su` to go into root:

```
su
```

You will need to enter the root password that you set up earlier.

Comment: Running make gives: "# This is a generated file, composed of the following suppression rules:" > default.supp
echo "# " exp-sgcheck.supp xfree-3.supp xfree-4.supp darwin10-drd.supp darwin10.supp  >> default.supp
cat exp-sgcheck.supp xfree-3.supp xfree-4.supp darwin10-drd.supp darwin10.supp  >> default.supp
cat: exp-sgcheck.supp: No such file or directory
cat: xfree-3.supp: No such file or directory
cat: xfree-4.supp: No such file or directory
cat: darwin10-drd.supp: No such file or directory
cat: darwin10.supp: No such file or directory
make: *** [default.supp] Error 1
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is expected behaviour (I can't test this right at the moment, but I remember seeing similar messages when I ran `make`). Run `make install` and see if it works.

Comment: make install gives me another bunch of errors
When I test it using valgrind ls -l
It says valgrind: command not found

Answer (score 3):

You may find it easier to use something like [macports](http://www.macports.org/). How to install that is probably beyond the scope of this question, but they have a [page](http://www.macports.org/install.php) dedicated to it on their site.

Once you have macports installed, you need to type:

```
sudo port install valgrind +universal
```

As you say you don't have any experience of command lines, let's just briefly go through the different parts of this command:

- `sudo` means the rest of the command will run as root, and will ask for your password. This is needed for the installer to have the correct permissions
- `port` is the command line tool for managing macports
- `install` is a command for `port`. Try `port help` to see a list of commands.
- `valgrind` tells macports what it should be installing
- `+universal` is a variant. This tells macports to configure valgrind to support 32 bit and 64 bit support.