# Trouble installing valgrind on macOS Sierra

Tags: macos, valgrind, macos-sierra

I'm trying to install valgrind on my Mac (Sierra). I first followed the instructions here: [How to build and install Valgrind on Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102143/how-to-build-and-install-valgrind-on-mac)

This gave an error, so then I tried a Homebrew installation using 
"brew install valgrind" which gave me errors and lead me to this: [Yosemite and Valgrind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26564125/yosemite-and-valgrind/27408219#27408219)

I have tried that too, but keep getting the error: "The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local Could not symlink include/valgrind/callgrind.h
/usr/local/include/valgrind is not writable." I tried "brew link valgrind" but that gave the same error.

I am just learning how to code so step-by-step help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the result of `ls -l /usr/local`?

Comment: There's a whole bunch of things: Cellar, Frameworks, Homebrew, texlive, bin, lib, bin, sbin, var, etc

Comment: What are the permissions on /usr/local? Give the result of `ls -ld /usr/local`

Comment: drwxr-xr-x  15 root  wheel  510 Jul  3 10:19 /usr/local

Comment: Homebrew does not have permissions to install things, there is a guide to solve this problem [here](https://digitizor.com/fix-homebrew-permissions-osx-el-capitan/). Step 4 should solve it.

Comment: Hmm I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148237/discussion-between-gavin-portwood-and-user3603077).

Comment: possibly `brew install valgrind --HEAD`